# Delta star, beginner question

Tags: motor, delta, star

[image]

Hi, can someone tall me why the line comes from behind the motor and comes back in front of it.
Is it because internal connection is crossed? for example, u->x v-y w->z. What am I missing?

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: For example, R line, to U contact to Z and back to U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because internal connection is crossed?

It is. The internal connections to the stator coils behind the 2 x 3 connection block are diagonal, as shown in the lower part of this diagram.

[image: motor wiring diagram from automationforum.co]
[Source](https://automationforum.co/how-to-connect-a-three-phase-motor-in-star-and-delta-connection/)

This allows a 3 phase motor to be wired in star or delta by itself (without an external star-delta starter) by placing straps horizontally or vertically across the connection block, as discussed in the [article](https://automationforum.co/how-to-connect-a-three-phase-motor-in-star-and-delta-connection/) accompanying the diagram and shown in the upper part of the picture. (The diagram shows an extra set of external connections. You can ignore the lower set of connections.)

In the case of your circuit the straps aren't used and all six connections are brought out so the star and delta connections can be made via contactors.

Answer (score 2):

The winding designations are U-X, V-Y and W-Z.

[image]

The 'Star' and 'Delta' connections are as shown below.

[image]

[image]

The power circuit has been altered accordingly.

[image]